# What will be my domain in case of google drive api push notifications?

Tags: android, web, google-api, google-drive-api, backend

I'm using the Google Drive API for an android app and a web app. I want to 'watch' a folder on google drive and whenever a change happens, I want both my apps to be notified. I know Google Drive already offers this via [the api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#overview). But the documentation says I have to first register my domain. What will be the domain for both of these? Also can someone guide me through the whole process? I am relatively new to backend dev and have gone through the documentation but the steps are not very clear.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Push Notification" seems missleading in this context. In reallity, the Google Drive API offers you to specifiy a callback URL. It will make a request to this callback URL whenever a specific event happens (e.g. when files change in a folder).

Check out the explanation on Twilio: [What is a Webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-webhook)

When the webhook is called, you need to send an actual push notification to your apps on your own. This can be done by using services like Firebase [Cloud-Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).

The process looks like this:

1. A change happens in your observed Google Drive folder
2. Google Drive will send a [`POST` request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#receiving-notifications)
3. Your server needs to receive the request and send a push notification to your mobile devices

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This process definitely makes more sense now. Just one more thing, will FCM also give me the required server to send and receive the requests?  And is it free?

Comment: @AkshatJ.No. But [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions?hl=en) or similar services by other providers can be used to host code which is executed whenever your url is called. This is a simpler approach for lightweight web-backend tasks. You don't have to maintain an own (virtual) server. But at scale, it can become costly, so check the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=en).